# Creating a Work Queue on a Thread

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, queue, dispatcher

I like the Distpatcher in the System.Windows.Threading namespace, and would like to use this object in a class library.  However, since it was created for WPF and and seems to be specific to the UI, I feel like I'm abusing its intended purpose by using it in a class library.

I'm wondering if there exists some other class that serves the same purpose (creating a queue of work items for a thread) but is better intended for use in a class library.  Essentially all I want to do is create a thread and, from another thread, asynchronously queue a bunch of delegates for it to run.

I could build something quite easily, but I would prefer to follow standard convention and use something that's already proven.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BlockingCollection` is exactly what you need then. The `Take` method blocks until an item appears in the queue which makes it ideal for these types of producer-consumer like scenarios.

```
public class Worker
{
  private BlockingCollection<Action> m_Queue = new BlockingCollection<Action>();

  public Worker()
  {
    var thread = new Thread(
      () =>
      {
        while (true)
        {
          Action action = m_Queue.Take();
          action();
        }
      });
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
  }

  public void QueueWorkItem(Action action)
  {
    m_Queue.Add(action);
  }
}
```

Comment: I love the simplicity of this solution.  I don't have to learn another API, and it solves my immediate need.  However, I think the Task features of the TPL in Tim Barrass's solution is something I will eventually need to learn.

Answer (score 1):

The TPL has taskschedulers that you can instantiate to handle work queues. Check out [this msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx). The default is to use the global ThreadPool, which you should be able to add tasks to with just:

```
Task myTask = Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
{                
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, I'm a queued task."); 
});
```

If you want more sophisticated queue management then you can implement your own taskscheduler -- there are many examples via the msdn link above.